# xcode: Why display delete icon on UITableViewCell the image is moved to right?

Tags: xcode, image, uitableview

My code here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

    }


    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flower.png"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

    imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    imageView.image = myImage;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    [imageView release];

    return cell;
}
```

After implement commitEditingStyle function, click edit button on left of navigation bar my image is moved to right. I want my image display on the center of each cell and don't move when the delete icon display. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code if your table is group syled:
`- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}`

Comment: is your table style plain ? FYI, the above should work on plain style tableviews in iOS 6

Comment: Yes my tableview is on plain style. I've tried on iOS 6 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the image to the contentview but to the view of the cell and set the autoresizing to none.

```
[imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
[cell addSubview:imageView];
```